# Is there an adjective or phrase for "to be dealt with"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I want an expression to refer a noun *to be processed* or *to be dealt with*. I think clauses a bit too long, while 'to-be-processed' phrase not elegant.

To specify my question in avoidance of ambiguous, I would state the context as explaining a model/method. I am about to write how the intermediate data between two procedures are like. So initially I consider sentence like "The ***to-be-computed/processed***(by second procedure) data have features that blablabla."

Comment: Can you include an example sentence please?

Comment: "outstanding" maybe "defn 2: not yet paid, solved, or done"  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of assigning "status" values to various (sub-)tasks within an organisation, for example,...

> [**pending**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pending) - about to happen or waiting to happen
>     *There were whispers that a deal was pending.*

Answer (score 0):

Backlog: [an accumulation of uncompleted work or matters needing to be dealt with.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/backlog)
("the company took on extra staff to clear the backlog of work")

Expressions such as the following might also work: in the works; on the back burner; on hold; on ice;

Also,"[have something on one's hands"](https://www.google.ro/amp/s/www.ldoceonline.com/license/amp/dictionary/have-something-somebody-on-your-hands) defined as "to have a difficult job, problem, situation etc to deal with" by Longman ( example: " If we don't straighten these things out right now, we're going to have a big mess on our hands.")

You can always just use handle, handled etc. : "It's being handled right now", or " someone's on it".

Your question is rather vague, so beyond these I can't help you any more, as It's just guesswork at this point.